# map in macro replace error with common lisp

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I want to use a macro to create a class instance.

What I mean is that i want to create a expression like :

```
(make-instance 'message :id id :mid mid)
```

**I define the class like this.**

```
(defclass message ()
  ((id
     :initarg :id
     :initform 0
     :accessor id)
   (mid
     :initarg :mid
     :initform 0
     :accessor mid)))

(defmethod print-object ((obj message) stream)
   (print-unreadable-object (obj stream :type t)
      (with-slots (id mid) obj
         (format stream "~A  ~A " id mid))))
```

**and the macro like this.**

```
 (defun slotlist (alist)
    (mapcan
       #'(lambda (x)
            (let* ((s (closer-mop:slot-definition-name x))
                   (k (intern (symbol-name s) :keyword))
                   (v (assoc k alist)))
                   (if v (list k (cdr v)))))
                (closer-mop:class-direct-slots (find-class 'message))))

(defmacro create-message (alist)
    (let ((a (gensym)))
       `(let ((,a (slotlist ,alist)))
            (make-instance 'message ,@a))))
```

**and the json-obj like :**

(setq json-obj '((:id . 1) (:mid . 2)))

when I apply the macro create-message

```
(create-message json-obj)
```

It expand like :

```
(LET ((#:G1111 (SLOTLIST JSON-ALIT)))
   (MAKE-INSTANCE 'MESSAGE . #:G1111))
```

but the instance does not init correctly because it shows that the value of the instance is
     #

Should i have to splice the map function string and use the apply function ?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Should you have to splice things _where_?  Should you have to use `apply` _where_?  It sounds like you're asking how you should perform your macroexpansion.  Can you show what the macro _should_ expand to?  That will help us understand what the macro _ought_ to do, and will help us debug what it's _actually_ doing.

Comment: I means that should i have to create a expression like (mapcan #'...) and use the apply to call the expression to create what i want in the macro.

Comment: What do you mean by "the symble will never get it value"?  What value are you expecting?  Also, could you please give us an english description of what the macro is supposed to do?  An example invocation with corresponding desired expansion would help as well.

Comment: Why would you write a macro to do that? Why not a function?

Comment: If what you want is to serialize an object to JSON, why not just use `cl-json`? It can do that... But there are more things conceptually wrong here: you want to have a method that specializes on `message` class that returns a JSON representation of `message` objects. You will have lots and lots of problems with this macro later because the list of all slots isn't something available before class finalization, but that may not happen when macro expands, or will force you to finalize the class inheritance before you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something important about your use case, but it seems to me that what you want can easily be implemented as a function.

In order to create a new `message` instance, we need something like `(make-instance 'message :id 1 :mid 2)`.  All this information is in `json-obj` -- we simply need to massage it into the correct format and use `apply`:.

```
(defun json-attr->arg-list (json-attr)
  (list (car json-attr)
        (cdr json-attr)))

(defun json-obj->arg-list (json-obj)
  (apply #'concatenate 'list
         (map 'list #'json-attr->arg-list json-obj)))

(defun create-message (json-obj)
  (apply #'make-instance 'message (json-obj->arg-list json-obj)))
```

Now, we can call `create-message` with your previously defined `json-obj`:

```
=> (create-message json-obj)

#<MESSAGE 1  2 >
```

Now, we could implement this as a macro, but what would be the point?  We can't know the value of `json-obj` before run-time, so there really isn't anything we can do at compile-time except basically inline the function we just wrote.  But (a) that would be unlikely to increase performance by any measurable amount in this case, and (b) that is not what macros are for -- use compiler hints for in-lining.

Plus, if you wanted to use `create-message` with a higher-order function, you would have to implement it as a function anyway.  For example, `(map 'list #'create-message list-of-json-objs)` would be a really handy way to create a list of `message` objects from a list of alists.  In common-lisp, a symbol can have both a macro and a function associated with it, so you *could* create both macro and function bindings for it.  But since you are not gaining any advantage from using a macro, all you would be doing is creating more work for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do, so I have no idea whether you should use the apply function or not.  I can, however, help you out with one problem with your code.

In the code you gave, you have a quasiquotation that starts with

```
`(let ((,insym ,json-obj))
```

You then escape from the quasiquotation with the form starting with

```
,(mapcan #'(lambda (x)
```

You have one level of quasi-quotation, and one unquote (comma) to match it.  So that form will be evaluated when the macro is expanded.  But then inside that same unquoted form, you attempt to unquote another form:

```
,insym
```

This is an error, as you have already escaped from the single level of quasiquotation.  To fix this error (although perhaps not the macro as a whole), you need to remove the last comma.

This paper might be useful in learning more details about quasiquotation:  http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/pepm99/bawden.pdf

Comment: I changed my presentation hope you can get it.

Comment: Ok, I've added another answer.  I'm leaving this one in case someone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that the `a` that you refer to within the quasi-quote list is the one you bound in the external `let` and it expands to a gensym.

Let me make a small example:

```
* (let ((b 'a)) `(let ((,b (foo))) (print ,@b)))

(LET ((A (FOO)))
  (PRINT . A))
```

As we can see, the `b` is bound to `a`, which is not a list, so splicing it in, we end up with a dotted pair.

If we instead skip expanding it, we get closer to right.

So, instead of what you have, you could try one of:

```
(defmacro create-message (alist)
    (let ((a (gensym)))
       `(let ((,a (slotlist ,alist)))
            (make-instance 'message ',a))))
```

or:

```
(defmacro create-message (alist)
  `(make-instance 'message (slotlist ,alist)))  ; You may want ',alist
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how'd you do this using `cl-json`:

```
(ql:quickload "cl-json")

(defclass message ()
  ((id :initarg :id :initform 0 :accessor id)
   (mid :initarg :mid :initform 0 :accessor mid)))

(cl-json:encode-json (make-instance 'message :mid 42 :id 13))
{"id":13,"mid":42}
```

Which is really all there is to it. You may want to read more here: http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/#STREAMING-API (The documentation is a bit hectic as is the API, but would still save you the time you've spend writing it from scratch).

---

As an aside: JSON isn't really all that good as it is often advertised. If you are free to choose the format, have a look at Protobuf or Trift (they are bad too, but not as bad as JSON) :)

Answer (score 0):

the question is that the macro do not know the value of the parameter , so it will be treat as  a symbol. So in the body of the macro , it will replace the symbol , not the value of the symbol.

```
,@(slotlist ,alist)
```

is error because in the body of ,@ can not include , to get symbol value.
and if you use the ,@(slotlist alist) the symbol alist will never eval corretly, the macro treat it as a symbol.

The correct way to sovle the problem is use eval function :

```
(defmacro create-message (alist)
    `(make-instance 'message ,@(slotlist (eval alist))))
```